# If there's any limitation of query parameter length in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running a REST API service using Cloud Run.

I get the following error when I send a GET request to the API with quite a long query parameter. (15000 bytes in total)

```
Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)!!1
```

Since I don't get the error when I send the identical request to the API running in my local environment,
I think this error isn't generated by the API but by Cloud Run.

In order to handle this issue, I'd like to ask

1. If there's any limitation of query parameter length in Cloud Run.
2. If so, what is the limitation (total byte length? etc)

Thank you.

Comment: The maximum request size including headers is 16 KB. However, it is bad practice to have query parameters longer than 1024 bytes. The entire URL should be limited to 2048 bytes. There are systems between you and Cloud Run (Google internal and Internet), there are limitations with libraries (OS and language), etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider splitting the query parameter to 1024 bytes each for multiple requests :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit but I had difficulties to find a clear documentation on this. Here, what I can say:

- Google (and Google cloud) are protected by a global, distributed proxy named [Google Front End (or GFE)](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design#google_front_end_service)
- GFE protects all the Google resources, your Cloud Run services included (GFE provide a DNS name, check the header in case of private services, discard L3 DDoS attacks,...)

So, you can't change this limit. I found it in the [HTTPS load balancer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#https-lb-header-limits), and because the HTTPS load balancer is also behind GFE (or is a part of GFE) the limit are the same!

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense to think the max header size of load balancer is as same as the one of Cloud Run.